# VBA Type mismatch when trying to increment text number

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to set up a code in MS Access that increments the last four positions of a text field. The numbers in the text field have seven digits. For example:

0010012

0010013

First three digits represent the manuacturer and the last four the product. These are the ones I want to increment. I am using the code below, which I found online, and it is supposed to be working but I keep getting the error: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

```
Dim varSifra As Variant
varSifra = DMax("[Sifra]", "tblProducts", "[Manufacturer] = " & Forms!frmProduct!Manufacturer)
Me.[Sifra] = Left(varSifra, 3) & Format(Val(Right(varSifra, 4)) + 1, "0000")
```

I tried the code without the Format function but instead of incremented number 0010014 I get 00114

Comment: Why don't you just `Format(varSifra+1, "0000000")`? Handling overflow isn't done anyways...

Comment: LS_dev, I could do it your way. But I still get the error

Comment: Is this Excel/Access?

Comment: It's Access ... forgot to mention that.

Comment: This is being called from a form, a suppose. Is `Sifra` defined in form as text?

Comment: You're right it's called from a form and Sifra is defined as text

Comment: Probably you are not getting any results. Try `If Not IsNull(varSifra) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can this help?

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print IncrementProduct("0010001") //Prints 0010002
    Debug.Print IncrementProduct("0010012") //Prints 0010013
    Debug.Print IncrementProduct("0010099") //Prints 0010100
End Sub


Function IncrementProduct(code As String) As String
    Dim manufacturerCode As String, padding As String, productCode As String

    manufacturerCode = VBA.Left$(code, 3)
    productCode = CInt(VBA.Right$(code, Len(code) - Len(manufacturerCode))) + 1
    padding = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 4 - Len(productCode))

    IncrementProduct = manufacturerCode & padding & productCode
End Function
```

Comment: I tried using your function, but I'm getting error "Method or data member not found" for Application.WorksheetFunction even though I've included Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library in the References. Are there any other references I have to include?

Comment: Not sure. The other option is to use an `IF` statement to get the padding correct e.g. `IF(Len(productCode) = 1, Then padding = "000"` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple Format call fine, however the input needs to be explicitly converted to a Long first:

```
Function IncProductNumber(Value)
    If IsNull(Value) Then
        Let IncProductNumber = Null
    Else
        Let IncProductNumber = Format(CLng(Value) + 1, "0000000")
    End If
End Function
```

Or, more generically, the desired padding could be inferred from the input:

```
Function IncTextNumber(Value)
    If IsNull(Value) Then
        Let IncTextNumber = Null
    Else
        Let IncTextNumber = Format(CLng(Value) + 1, String$(Len(Value), "0"))
    End If
End Function
```

IncTextNumber("0123") will produce "0124", IncTextNumber("00999") will produce "01000" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim tempManProd As String, tempNumToInc As Integer

tempManProd = 'get the value you are wanting to increment
tempNumToInc = CInt(right(tempManProd, 4))
tempNumToInc = tempNumToInc + 1

'This will make sure that the 0s get added back to the front of the product
Do While (Len(tempManProd & "") + Len(tempNumToInc & "")) < 7
  tempManProd = tempManProd & "0"
Loop

tempManProd = tempManProd & CStr(tempNumToInc)
```